# Algebraic closure and field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

K is a field.
Are the following properties always true?

1. For every field extension L|K with $[L:K]\in\{1,\infty\}$, K is algebraically closed
2. K algebraically closed, so for every field extension L|K we have $[L:K]\in\{1,\infty\}$

I dont see how to solve that and why it should be true at all. Can anyone help me there?

Comment: As stated, these are false, because they are asserting that every field is algebraically closed...

Comment: Neither statement is stated very clearly.

Comment: @EricWofsey  what do you mean? can you elaborate why they are false? Or do you mean i phrased it poorly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restated, it appears your question is how to prove the following statement:

A field K is algebraically closed if and only if the only field $L$ which is a finite extension of $K$ is $L=K$.

The proof is very easy . . .

**The forward direction:**

Assume $K$ is algebraically closed, and $L$ is a finite extension of $K$.

But a finite extension of a field is an algebraic extension, hence $L$ is algebraic over $K$.

Since $K$ is algebraically closed, $L \subseteq K$.

But $L$ is an extension of $K$, so $K \subseteq L$.

Therefore $L=K$.

**The reverse direction:**

Let $K$ be a field, and suppose the only field $L$ which is a finite extension of $K$ is $L=K$.

Let $\bar{K}$ be an algebraically closed field containing $K$.

Of course $K \subseteq \bar{K}$.

For the reverse inclusion, let $a \in \bar{K}$.

Then $a$ is algebraic over $K$, so $a$ is a root of some polynomial $p \in K[x]$, of degree $n$, say.

Letting $L=K(a)$, it follows that $[L:K] \le n$, so $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, hence $L = K$, so $a \in K$.

Thus, $\bar{K} \subseteq K$, and hence $K = \bar{K}$.

Therefore $K$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Im a bit confused. Are you sure this proves the original 2 points? What confuses me the most is that you dont talk about $[L:K]=\infty$ ($[L:K]=\{1,\infty\}$)

Comment: @SquareJoe: $[L:K]=\infty$ is equivalent to saying "$L$ is an extension of $K$, but not a finite extension of $K$", and $[L:K]=1$ is equivalent to saying "$L=K$". Thus, saying $[L:K]\in \{1,\infty\}$ is the same as saying "If $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, then $L=K$".

Comment: and what if $[L:K]=\infty$? is it still algebraic then?

Comment: Oh my godness. I completely misunderstood. This explains why i struggled so much finding a solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I see the issue . . . As written, statement $1$ makes no sense. I re-interpreted it as how it was probably intended. Here's the likely intended version of statement $1$ . . .

Comment: **Statement 1 (recast):** If for all extensions $L$ of $K$, we have $[L:K]\in\{1,\infty\}$, then $K$ is algebraically closed.
$$$$
**Statement 2 (recast):** If $K$ is algebraically closed, then for all extensions $L$ of $K$, we have $[L:K]\in\{1,\infty\}$.

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Is it from a book?

Comment: Its from a friend. He often asks questions like this. They dont have to be true by the way. He comes up with these kind of questions and asks if its true or not and then why

Comment: Sorry to ask again. If i have $[L:K]=\infty$ then K doesnt have to be algebraic closed right? So 1) doesnt hold true while 2) does because of your statement Like $[\mathbb{R}: \mathbb{Q}]$ for $\pi$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72581/discussion-between-quasi-and-squarejoe).

Answer (score 0):

For (2), by contradiction, if there is some field $L$ such that $[L:K]$ is finite (but not $1$), then all elements in $L$ satisfy a polynomial with finite degree.  But if $K$ is algebraically closed then the polynomial be solved in $K$ and hence $L=K$ and $[L:K]=1$.

For (1), if we have a polynomial $f(x)$, and its roots are not all in $K$, then there are some element $\alpha$ not in $K$ such that it satisfies this polynomial so that we can write a new extension $K[\alpha]/K$ which has finite degree (but not $1$ since $\alpha\notin K$.

The proofs above are not very rigorous but I guess it is a good draft for how to solve them.  For comments above that stating that those statements are false, I would like to know what additional assumption I have made in proofs above.  Thank you very much.